# Debugging shared object in eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, gdb

I am creating contrib module in PostgreSQL where i have a problem debugging in eclipse Juno. I was following the debugging process outlined @ http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Eclipse#Debugging_PostgreSQL_from_Eclipse

In short

1. Start PostgreSQL server from eclipse, ensured that contrib so is being loaded
2. Start debug configuration of type C-Attach to application and attach it to PostgreSQL server process.
3. Execute psql from command prompt and expect execution to stop at the breakpoint in contrib module.

Problem is breakpoints are ignored in contrib module and i keep seeing message
"Detaching after fork from child process XXXX".

I have ensured the following
1. Debug configuration points contrib shared library so.
2. Debug configuration points to contrib source
3. In preferences for Debug i have added source lookup path pointing to contrib module.

Note: I am compiling contrib module outside eclipse, for some reason i cannot drop the make file in the make view within eclipse.

Any pointers would help
regards
Sameer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. I was attaching gdb to the wrong process i.e the Postmaster. It should be attached to the process id forked from the Postmaster once psql (SQL client) connects to the PostgreSQL instance
Thanks